# Text file empty after building Unity3D project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, system.io.file

During run time i record Input which i want to be played back in the build. So i create a txt file under the Resources directory which i fill with text throughout run time with a StreamWriter. The contents stays there in scene mode, after closing the project, but not after building and running it. I've been searching the net for a while but didn't find anything related to my problem. I tried using the StreamingAssets folder, but i didn't get it to work either. Thanks for any help.

```
    if (!Directory.Exists("Assets/Resources/Recordings"))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory("Assets/Resources/Recordings");
    }

    if (!File.Exists("Assets/Resources/Recordings/Challenge1.txt"))
    {
        File.WriteAllText("Assets/Resources/Recordings/Challenge1.txt", "");
    }
```

Edit: Switch (mode)

```
     case Mode.Record:
        oldSequence.init ();
        currentSequence.init ();

        inputRecordStream = new StreamWriter (FilePath, false); // will overwrite new file Stream
        if (inputRecordStream.ToString () == "")
        {
            Stop ();
            Debug.Log ("InputReplay: StreamWriter(" + FilePath + "), file not found ?");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            inputRecordStream.AutoFlush = true;
            SetInputStd ();
        }
        break;
```

Record method:

```
private void Record(float time)
{
    currentSequence.init ();
    currentSequence.t = time;

    // store only true boolean
    foreach (KeyCode vkey in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)))
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (vkey))
            currentSequence.gK.Add (vkey);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (vkey))
            currentSequence.gKD.Add (vkey);
        if (Input.GetKeyUp (vkey))
            currentSequence.gKU.Add (vkey);
    }

    currentSequence.mP = Input.mousePosition;

    currentSequence.mWP = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (currentSequence.mP);

    currentSequence.mSD = Input.mouseScrollDelta;

    foreach (string virtualAxis in AxisList)
        currentSequence.vA.Add (Input.GetAxis (virtualAxis));

    foreach (string ButtonName in ButtonList)
    {
        if (Input.GetButton (ButtonName))
            currentSequence.vB.Add (ButtonName);
        if (Input.GetButtonDown (ButtonName))
            currentSequence.vBD.Add (ButtonName);
        if (Input.GetButtonUp (ButtonName))
            currentSequence.vBU.Add (ButtonName);
    }

    // only write if something changed
    if (AnyChange(oldSequence, currentSequence))
    {
        //Debug.Log (JsonUtility.ToJson (newSequence));
        inputRecordStream.WriteLine (JsonUtility.ToJson (currentSequence));
        oldSequence = currentSequence;
    }
}
```

Comment: your file challenge1.txt is empty, and its normal, you write "" inside it.!

Comment: Oh, ok. So i haven't managed to include them in the build, i've just created new files in it. Do you know how i could include the text files i create in run time in the build? @Frenchy

Comment: yes but show more code..how you build your text

Answer (score 0):

```cs
File.WriteAllText("Assets/Resources/Recordings/Challenge1.txt", "");
```

When using [`File.WriteAllText(string path  string text )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-5.0), make sure you include the data you want written to the file. You have only included "" which would write no characters to the file.

To import the assets to use at runtime you can use [`Resources.Load(string path)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html). This will allow you to access the file in unity scripts during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you .close the file at the end of your script, which actually saves the file to be able to reopen later!

Comment: Please add code snippet for the same and reference links.